# Mac: saving .exe to PATH for selenium web driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, path

I am not a professional developer... trying to save chromedriver to PATH variable so i can use selenium with python.

following this page for instructions on this page
https://medium.com/@himanshuagarwal1395/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-sierra-f5978369b255

I open bash_profile with `nano .bash_profile`

I made a directory `user/mysusername/selenium/`
then saved my file `chromedriver` in this directory with the python script i and using selenium with. 
I have tried to save my path to the chromedriver.exe file as such

`export PATH="/User/baldoa/selenium/ChromeDriver.exe:$PATH"`

I follow the steps to save appropriately according to this page. I am not sure

i still get the following error :

```
a8206602016e:selenium baldoa$ python destruction.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/baldoa/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium

/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
stdin=PIPE)
File "/Users/baldoa/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line
709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/Users/baldoa/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line   
1344, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/users/baldoa
/selenium/chromedriver.exe': 'C:/users/baldoa/selenium/chromedriver.exe'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "destruction.py", line 7, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Chrome("""C:/users/baldoa/selenium/chromedriver.exe""")
File "/Users/baldoa/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium

/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/Users/baldoa/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium

/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe'    
executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com  
/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Please paste your code of driver instantiation. It would help in understanding. Also while you are using mac why C:\ is needed? Same for .exe extension?

Comment: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.41/ - I am not sure how to look at the code for this driver, but here is the link to the driver

Comment: changed it to `browser = webdriver.Chrome("""Users/baldoa/selenium/chromedriver""")`

Comment: with ` export PATH="/User/baldoa/selenium/bin:$PATH"`    i now can see `Users/baldoa` after typing `pwd` in the command prompt... not really sure how this is supposed to work... am i supposed to make a path to the file? the folder the file is in? ... it is in the directory named selenium

Comment: by code I meant the code you wrote for opening browser window.